# Sort table data in descending order Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I'm sorting a value stored in `NSArray` using `NSSortDescriptor` in descending order and the sorted value is displayed in the console.

But zhr sorted table data is not sorted when table view is reloaded.

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *descriptor = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Priority"  ascending:NO]];
self.searchResult = [self.responseData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptor];
NSLog(@"Sorted Array %@", self.searchResult);
```

Comment: add tableview datasource methods .

Comment: Can you show your dataSource methods? You should use searchResult there. And be sure to call [tableView reloadData] after sorting your array

Comment: yes, i reloaded tableview.  [self.taskTableView reloadData];

Comment: i have included my dataSource method. - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.searchResult)
    {
        return [self.searchResult count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.taskDate count];
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *brandDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Priority" ascending:NO];
 NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
 NSArray *sortedArray = [tripStatusArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
 [yourTableView reloadData];
```

Use `sortedArray` for loading data on your `tableView`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this method but its not loading the sorted table data

Comment: @SherineSJ did you reloadTableview after this method? If not check my edited answer

Comment: yes, i reloaded tableView. I tried your edited answer too, its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSArray *SortedData = [yourDict or Array allKeys];
        NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: YES];
       SortedData = [SortedData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

Comment: yourDict is dictionary or array?

Comment: it is a temp array in which you have to put your array's or dictionary's value which you want to sort